# Reference for dummy variable regression for repeated measurements

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, references

I want to analyze some repeated measures data using a dummy variable for each measurement unit. This is one approach to deal with the fact that the data is not i.i.D. when repeated-measurements are present (in addition to classical repeated-measures ANOVA, multivariate ANOVA and mixed modeling, see Keselman & Algina, 2001), but I am missing a reference for that. Therefore my question is:

- **What is a reference for coding subjects as a fixed effect in repeated-measures analysis?**

Keselman, H. J., Algina, J., & Kowalchuk, R. K. (2001). The analysis of repeated measures designs: A review. British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 54(1), 1–20. doi:10.1348/000711001159357

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you could find a reference in psychology that will more suit your fancy, but Angrist and Pischke's *[Mostly Harmless Econometrics](http://books.google.com/books/about/Mostly_Harmless_Econometrics.html?id=ztXL21Xd8v8C)* has the most straightforward discussion related to such panel designs I have come across. You can just open up right to chapter 5 and take a few minutes to digest the related material.

It is also just a wonderful book on observational/quasi-experimental research designs to have in general (it is cheap too).

Comment: It is a wonderful book indeed! And I like its style.